# Assumption of Outlier Detection's methods

Tags: outliers

It seems some methods such as Dixon and Tukey were developed under the assumption of a Gaussian distribution and may not be appropriate for the non-Gaussian data. Now I was wondering which method for outlier detection should be used for non-gaussian data.

Comment: Grubbs' test is the most sensitive to departures from normality.  Actually Dixon's ratio test is robust to departures from normality in small samples.  For more details see this post https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38105/dixon-test-and-normal-distribution/38125#38125 .

Comment: The tag on outliers leads to hundreds of questions. There is hardly any need for another. You should read several of the most highly upvoted answers. I'd say that testing for outliers is far from being standard or even the most common approach. Rather many people seek to accommodate outliers in models which render them less surprising.

Comment: Adjusted Box plot method depending on the large masking gaps between variables.